# MogoDB with Angular JS without Expressjs and Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I want to use MongoDB with Angular JS without using ExpressJS or NodeJS or anyother layer in middle.

Regards

Comment: You need some sort of server-layer to connect to the MongoDB instance, unless such service exists that allows you to interact with a Mongo database using REST. MongoLab has such feature, but shouldn't be used on the client-side as you are exposing the API key, therefore jeopardising the security of your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible, unless you want to give users of your *AngularJS* application full access to your server (do not exclude possibility of rootkits through MongoDB application).

Middle server is needed as a gatekeeper: pass through only legitimate requests to database, blocking any sensitive or restricted data passing to user.

The fact that you are strugglying to find a client-side JavaScript to communicate with MongoDB is a good sign that such practice is discouraged.